# Create global QHash variable using qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a basic chat application using qt c++ in which server has to serve the multiple clients using threads, now i want to store socket descriptors and name of the respective user using QHash variable.
so i am really not understanding how to declare a global QHash variable so that each thread can update the values to that variable.
I did try storing socket descriptor into sqlite database but it did worked out. How to proceed further?

Comment: wrap the hash in a class which synchronizes the access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your hash into a class. Then read about thread safety and about QMutex.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make evertything global declaring it with the necessary visibility or make it static though it is bad practice to work with global storage accessed by the threads directly. If you really want to keep the track of sockets you can create a sort of cache where the thread could register and unregister new/complete chat session. Also, you have to think about concurecny a bit since multiple threads could register at the same moment and it breaks your code at this moment.